# Выборка агрегированных значений с учетом null

Tags: sql, sql-server, null

Всем привет!

Есть таблица перемещений книг с полки на полку допустим:

```
create table moves (
    moves_id int not null identity,
    book_id int not null,           --Книга
    rack_id int not null,           --Стеллаж
    board_id int not null,          --Полка
    date_from datetime not null,    --Дата поступления на стеллаж и полку (равно предыдущему date_to)
    date_to datetime null,          --Дата забора со стеллажа и полки (равно предыдущему date_from)
    primary key (moves_id)
)
```

Нужно для каждой книги вывести:

```
book_id     - Книгу
rack_id     - Стеллаж
date_from   - дату поступления на стеллаж вне зависимости от полки
date_to     - дату забора со стеллажа вне зависимости от полки
```

При этом нужно учесть что перемещения книг могут осуществляться как со стеллажа на стеллаж, так и в рамках одного стеллажа: с полки на полку.

Если date_to равно null - значит книга до сих пор лежит на этом стеллаже и полке.

Вот тестовые данные на примере одной книги:

```
insert into moves (book_id, rack_id, board_id, date_from, date_to) values
(8000, 56, 20, '01.02.2018 13:40:20.000', '21.02.2018 14:30:00.000'),
(8000, 56, 21, '21.02.2018 14:30:00.000', '10.03.2018 19:39:00.000'),
(8000, 56, 22, '10.03.2018 19:39:00.000', '15.03.2018 12:20:00.000'),
(8000, 60, 40, '15.03.2018 12:20:00.000', '16.03.2018 14:00:00.000'),
(8000, 60, 41, '16.03.2018 14:00:00.000', '19.03.2018 17:30:00.000'),
(8000, 60, 42, '19.03.2018 17:30:00.000', '01.04.2018 10:40:00.000'),
(8000, 56, 23, '01.04.2018 10:40:00.000', '05.04.2018 20:10:00.000'),
(8000, 56, 24, '05.04.2018 20:10:00.000', null)
```

Пробовал по разному агрегировать, и через cte и иначе не выходит, зашел в тупик, подскажите решение, заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```
select book_id, max(rack_id) rack_id, min(date_from) date_from,
       case when count(1)!=count(date_to) then NULL
            else max(date_to) end date_to
  from (
    select book_id, rack_id, date_from, date_to,
           sum(grp) over(partition by book_id order by date_from) grp
      from (
        select *, 
               case when rack_id!=lag(rack_id) over(partition by book_id order by date_from)
                    then 1 else 0 end grp
          from moves
      ) x
  ) y
 group by book_id, grp
```

В подзапросе `x` делаем поле `grp` равным 1 в случае, если у строки изменился стеллаж, по сравнению с предыдущей строкой по дате. Уровнем выше, в `y` накапливаем кумулятивную сумму колонки `grp`, таким образом получая номера групп на которые надо разбить выборку. На верхнем уровне запроса остается сгруппировать по этой колонке и если в группе встречался NULL (количество записей в группе не равно количеству not null значений поля date_to) то вернуть NULL вместо даты.

P.S. Настоятельно рекомендую, если книга до сих пор на полке дату окончания делать не NULL, а например 01.01.3000. Тогда все запросы к этой таблице станут гораздо проще, например узнать была ли книга на полке в определенную дату можно будет просто `искомая_дама between date_from and date_to` и не надо будет писать сложные выражения с `or date_to is null`. При этом запросы упростятся не только внешне, но и выполняться будут быстрее, при OR и проверке на null индексы скорее всего использоваться не смогут.

Comment: lag(rack_id) - ?

Comment: @noanother `lag() over(... order by x)` возвращает значение колонки из предыдущей записи в указанной сортировке https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql