# 2 группировки к 1 таблице

Tags: sql-server

Как можно реализовать 2 группировки к 1 таблице? В одном запросе.

```
    -- Все с дублями
    SELECT CAST(
      CAST(YEAR(getdate()) AS VARCHAR(4)) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(dateMonth AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(dateDay AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
   AS date) as 'База1 или период', count(*) as Всего
        FROM Leads
            GROUP BY 'База1 или период'
                ORDER BY dateDay

    -- Все без дублей
    SELECT CAST(
      CAST(YEAR(getdate()) AS VARCHAR(4)) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(dateMonth AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(dateDay AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
   AS date) as 'База1 или период', count(*) as 'Без дублей'
        FROM Leads
            WHERE doubleCheck_State is null
                GROUP BY dateDay, dateMonth
                    ORDER BY dateDay
```

Да дата как бы уже формируется, как склеить вот так. Без нее хотя бы объясните)

[image: Вот выход, так надеюсь понятнее. Да хотя бы с любыми полями]

Comment: они противоречат друг другу. приведите пример входных данных и что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. мне сложно например представить как могла бы выглядеть информация, одновременно сгруппированная по двум противоречащим критериям

Comment: дата, поле1, поле2 вот что хочу увидеть на выходе. Знаю что противоречат, но как то же можно это сделать.

Comment: Сделать наверняка можно. но надо сначала понять как именно оно должно выглядеть в виде данных. так что повторяю: приведите пример входных данных в таблице и результат, который ожидаете получить

Comment: id dateMonth dateDay 
1         1              1
2         1              2

dateDay + dateMonth + 2018 
На выходе Дата Кол1 Кол2

Comment: Вот как выглядят нормально заданные вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/812177/194569  Для составления любого запроса, а следовательно и ответа необходимо видеть структуру таблицы вместе с данными и так же в виде таблицы те же данные, но уже в преобразованном виде, что бы было понятно что откуда образовалось. По вашему примеру совершенно не ясно как число 2018 получается, когда на входе есть только  несколько единиц и пара двоек

Comment: А еще бывает полезны готовые скрипты на создание тестовых данных https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/811774/194569 для написания ответа часто нужен контрольный пример на котором проверять ответ. я например ни одного ответа не пишу, не проверив его работу в реальной БД, а тратить время на набивание тестовых данных и тем более придумывая их самомуу с потолка мало кто из отвечающих готов

Comment: у Вас же получается группировка по "База1 или период" совпадает с группировкой по дню и месяцу (ибо это поле зависит только от дня и месяца) или я что-то путаю? Если не путаю, то можно использовать только одну группировку и получать второе значение по SUM и CASE

Comment: Первое значение получается без условия, второе WHERE doubleCheck_State is null.

Answer (score 0):

```
with  stat1  as (SELECT CAST(
      CAST(YEAR(getdate()) AS VARCHAR(4)) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(dateMonth AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(dateDay AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
   AS date) as 'База1 или период', dateDay as 'Фактическая дата', count(*) as Всего
        FROM Leads
            GROUP BY dateDay, dateMonth

                --ORDER BY 'База1 или период'
                                            ),
    -- Все без дублей
    stat2  as (SELECT CAST(
      CAST(YEAR(getdate()) AS VARCHAR(4)) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(dateMonth AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
      RIGHT('0' + CAST(dateDay AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
   AS date) as 'База1 или период', dateDay as 'Фактическая дата', count(*) as 'Без дублей'
        FROM Leads
            WHERE doubleCheck_State is null
                GROUP BY dateDay, dateMonth
    --              --ORDER BY 'База1 или период'
                    )
    select s1.[База1 или период], s1.[Фактическая дата], s1.Всего, s2.[Без дублей], s1.Всего-s2.[Без дублей] as Дубли from stat1 s1
        inner join stat2 s2 on s2.[База1 или период]=s1.[База1 или период]
        order by 'База1 или период'
```

В общем сделал хранимку и сделал вот так.

Answer (score 0):

Группировка одинаковая по сути. Отличаются только условием. Заменим `COUNT` на `SUM` по этому условию:

```
SELECT CAST(
  CAST(YEAR(getdate()) AS VARCHAR(4)) +
  RIGHT('0' + CAST(dateMonth AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) +
  RIGHT('0' + CAST(dateDay AS VARCHAR(2)), 2) 
   AS date) as 'База1 или период',  count(*) as Всего,  
  SUM(CASE WHEN doubleCheck_State IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) as 'Без дублей'  
    FROM Leads
        WHERE doubleCheck_State is null
            GROUP BY dateDay, dateMonth
                ORDER BY dateDay
```